# Excel Formula to interpret 4.15 as 4 hours, 15 minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel, equations

I am creating a timesheet/rota for my company and each single cell contains the IN time and OUT time, presented as "9-3".

I have created a function which will SUM the string of 6 days, calculating how much *numerical difference* there is between 9 and 3, with the 3 being calculated as 15 within the formula. This works fine as a flat time, however the time interpretation breaks when including anything other than a whole number. "9.30-3" returns a number which does not interpret as the correct time. This is understandable as I'm not registering the numbers as time, however this is predominately due to the format of the source data- namely the hyphenated range.

I understand that the time calculation is resolved by having the correct decimal timing and reformatting the cell to display the interpreted time, however the nature of my source data won't allow this, or at least I have to alter an already huge equation to correctly quantify the time from the decimal.

Also, it is important to know that the information entered **will** be in the format of 4.15 for 4:15PM, not 15/100ths of the hour as Excel will read it as.

Comment: Wrap each time in a `TIMEVALUE`. So, `=(TIMEVALUE(D1)-TIMEVALUE(D2))` will give you the difference. Refer to this guide. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/

Comment: @Alex, your suggestion overlooks the issue that the delimiter is a decimal rather than a colon.

Comment: How does Excel differentiate 4.15 as 4:15PM vs. 4:15AM (just by testing relative values of start and end times)?

Comment: If you specify the time formatting in the cell, Excel should do the rest. 4.15 would always be assumed to be 4.15am, but if you format the cell for 12 hour format and enter 16.15, it will sort it out. All times and dates are held in memory in 24hour format, you just apply formatting to it. In this case, the issue is that there is already a huge equation which would need altering, but this will give the most maintainable end result.

Comment: " the information entered will be in the format of 4.15 for 4:15PM, " - so what happens for 4.15am?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your input! This has been very useful and I ticked an answer which has worked-- I'm still trying to sort it into a single cell without it pulling any errors.

Effectively I have this: `=SUM(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A4,FIND("-",A4)-1),".",":")))-(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A4,FIND("-",A4)+1,9999),".",":")))`--This pulls the full time post-hyphen, deducts the figure from the time pre-hyphen, then substitutes the result's decimal for the required colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I managed to actually do this myself. I realised that the time format wasn't going to be very easily pulled from the cell, so I decided to parse out the elements of the cell. This means, from a cell that reads "9.30-5.15" in text format, I need excel to understand:

- Start shift at 9 **hours**
- & 30 **minutes**
- & 0 seconds
- Leave shift at 5 **hours**
- & 15 **minutes**
- & 0 seconds
- 5 hours is less than 9 hours, so add 12 hours to account for 24 hours
- Deduct the now-larger time from the now-less time

The following formula is pretty ugly to look at but it certainly works (up to a point).

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),TIME(0,0,0),IFERROR(IF((--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,9999))<=(--LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)),TIME(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH("-",A1))-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1))),IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1,FIND("-",A1))),0),0)-TIME(IFERROR(MID(A1,1,SEARCH(".*-",A1)-1),(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))),IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH(".*-",A1)+1,SEARCH("-",A1)-SEARCH(".*-",A1)-1),0),0)+TIME(12,0,0),TIME(IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1,SEARCH("-",A1))-1),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1))),IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1,FIND("-",A1))),0),0)-TIME(IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(".*-",A1)-1),(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1))),IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,SEARCH(".*-",A1)),0),0)),(TIME(0,0,0))))
```

This formula allows for a blank cell to be counted as zero time, also for a cell populated with words to be counted as zero, so as to not ruin the calculation.

The purpose of this is for a monthly rota to be created, and time is input in the following formats:

- 9-3
- 9.30-3
- 9-3.30
- 9.30-3.30

This means the shift manager can enter times (which can change with daily variance) and the sheet will calculate 6 working days of the week, highlighting the calculation when reaching their hours-quota through conditional formatting, as in the image:
[Timesheet Rota Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMAKb.png)

Hope this helps anyone trying to do the same!! There's only one bug I haven't dealt with - you can't enter a 2-digit hour as the second time. So you can enter 3-9.59 but you can't enter 3-10. This is simply because nobody where I am designing this for works past 6pm, and I didn't *need* to fix it.. so why bother. It's not too difficult to fix however, if you'd like to weed it out to use it.

Please let me know if this comes in useful for you, as I've been scrambling my brain to make this work the way it does for some time now!

Comment: In fact, if anyone is interested, I can send a 2017 calendar template with all these calculations applied. Just let me know as it's a huge benefit to us.

Answer (score 3):

Say we have in **A1**:

8.45-2.23

In **B1** enter:

```
=--LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,9999)
```

These two cells are "decimalized" versions of the start and stop times.  In **D1** we adjust for AM/PM:

```
=IF(C1<B1,C1+12,C1)
```

Finally in **E1** enter:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(D1,".",":"))-TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,".",":"))
```

[image]

With reasonable formatting applied.

These can be combined into a single formula if desired:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE((IF((--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,9999))<(--LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)),(--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,9999))+12,(--MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,9999)))),".",":"))-TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE((--LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)),".",":"))
```

Comment: This is a great response and I really appreciate it. I'm trying to fit it all into a single cell however and trying to deal with all the errors that appear. Will post my final, single cell result!

Comment: @GrayRoberts  See my edit

Comment: That's really great - thank you for that!! I've been absent because I've been trying my damndest to make it work, but I don't think it actually works in a practical way. The person who will use this is likely to type any time value ranging from 9-3 to 9.15-9.30 and I don't think your equation accounts for when a decimal isn't used.

I really do appreciate your time put into this, but I'm having such trouble and you're the only person I've found that is pointing me in the right direction on this. So thank you!

Comment: @GrayRoberts  if you need more help,tomorrow is good.....I am travelling today.

Comment: You're a genuine hero. Thank you for responding so quickly - I look forward to tomorrow, and I hope you have safe journeys today!

Comment: So to give you a clearer picture of my problem - I need to find a 6-day total of hours worked for one person on one row.

I am finding that the clearest, most reliable way for this is to actually enter the Time function, then search the cell for figures on each side of a hyphen, however there are a few variables and I'm having real trouble fitting it all together.

I am trying to have one single cell calculate a mixture of entries-- as an example;
Monday: "9-3" (6 hours)
Tuesday: "9.15-3" (5h 45m)
Wednesday: "9.15-3" (5h 45m)
Thursday: "9.15-3.30" (6h 15m) and so on- and I'm so stuck!